# MongoDB: How to search in document array element

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm sure this is a trivial question for the most of the Mongo users however, I was unlucky in finding the right answer. 
I have a collection of documents like

```
{
  _id:"2a1fd96c-73c5-49e1-a8ca-bd03a20c0197",
  timestamp:1519725979178,
  storeID:"xxx",
  unitID: "yyy",
  status:[1, 0, 1, 0],
  _rev:"1-8019f22bf26b4d6cb99ae5460b3e0c65"
}
```

I need to find all documents that:

```
storeID = "xxx" AND unitID = "yyy" AND status[2] = 1
```

My filter entry that works with Compass

```
{'status.2': 1,storeID:'xxx',unitID:'yyy'}
```

However when I am trying to convert it into Js code

```
Model.find({'status.2': 1,storeID:'xxx',unitID:'yyy'})
```

Nothing is returned.

Comment: Could you please provide how are you performing the search? (not just the `Model.find...`)

Comment: That's the right query; does your `Model` work to perform other queries?

Comment: @JohnnyHK, yes, when I removed `'status.2': 1` from the query everything was fine. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the schema definition for `Model`?

Comment: @JohnnyHK, I owe you a +1 as you pushed me in the right direction. I forgot to update the schema where `status` was declared as `String`, not `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple hours of pulling my hair out, I nailed the problem.
The filtering query
`{'status.2':1,storeID:'xxx',unitID:'yyy'}` and `{'status.2':{$eq:1},storeID:'xxx',unitID:'yyy'}` was actually okay.

Unfortunatelly, I used `.find()` along with Model instead of invoking it in collection scope:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    MyShema = new Schema({/* definition */}),
    Model = mongoose.model('MyShema'),
    filter = {'status.2':1,storeID:'xxx',unitID:'yyy'};


// BEFORE
let cursor = Model.find(fd); //returns total=0


// AFTER
let cursor = Model.collection.find(fd); //returns total=80

cursor.count()
    .then(total=>console.log('total',total))
    .catch(error=>console.log(error));
```

Somehow bizarrely when I removed `'status.2':1` from the filtering options, both instances of the cursor were returning an identical amount of documents.
The reason for that that was so pathetic - the `status` was declared in Schema as `String` whereas it should be obviously `Array`!